# IE8 Checkbox or Radios Select

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, internet-explorer-8

Is there any way to run the radio or checkbox in Internet Explorer 8

I think the solution might be in jquery with some values ​​to emulate?

```
:active
:before
:after
```

Is example: http://jsfiddle.net/x5E3W/

Answer (score 0):

By "run" do you mean it should have the same style in IE 8?
As the example uses a lot of CSS3 features (rounded corners, shadows), the answer is most definitely no.

Comment: Sure that's obvious, what I want is to run the check when selecting else I care.

Your answer is not a solution

Comment: In my usage, "run" basically means "work" rather than look good. From what I have seen, the checkboxes should work fine, but look ugly. You asked whether there is any way, I answered that there is probably none and why I think so. If someone else proves me wrong, I am also in for it, one never stops learning.